# Using texture painting on an existing node material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, texture-painting

blender newbie here. For a school project I'm trying to create sort of a promo image of a table with a pattern laser etched into it. My first plan was to create a wood material using nodes and then using texture painting overlay the pattern on parts of the model where I need it, but I'm struggling with this. Can texture painting and node materials even be combined? If not, what would the approach to doing something like this be? Also for the texture painting, is it possible to use an image with a transparent background as some sort of a stamp, or am I stuck retracing the pattern by hand?

Thanks a lot for all answers!

I'm using Blender 2.92, rendering through Cycles

--Edit--

Example of the effect I'm going for. Image or a pattern etched/engraved (not sure which to use, sorry, English is not my first language) into wood. I don't need to deform the mesh of the object, having the image just stuck to the surface would be more than enough.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done. Here is a very crude example:

[image: crude texture paint overlay]

Here's the node tree:

[image: Node tree]

To paint with an image stencil, create a new Brush and set the type to "Image or Movie" and then select the pattern image as the image in the Image settings.